# How can I fetch a list of available hours in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, outsystems

Here's the use case: a client can register a schedule in a room from one date to another. I'm trying to implement a calendar in which the client can click on a day and get the available hours to schedule that room. This is what I've tried so far, it only works if the day has a single schedule associated with it:

```
SELECT {Hours}.*
FROM {Hours}
WHERE {Hours}.[Id] BETWEEN (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN @DateInput = {Schedule}.[StartDate] THEN 0
            WHEN @DateInput > {Schedule}.[StartDate] AND @DateInput < {Schedule}.[EndDate] THEN 23
            WHEN @DateInput = {Schedule}.[EndDate] THEN {Schedule}.[EndHour]
        END
    FROM {Schedule}
    WHERE {Schedule}.[RoomId] = @RoomInput
    ) AND (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN @DateInput = {Schedule}.[StartDate] THEN {Schedule}.[StartHour] - 1
            WHEN @DateInput > {Schedule}.[StartDate] AND @DateInput < {Schedule}.[EndDate] THEN 0
            WHEN @DateInput = {Schedule}.[EndDate] THEN 23
        END
    FROM {Schedule}
    WHERE {Schedule}.[RoomId] = @RoomInput
    )
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help here.

Comment: We need your `CREATE TABLE` statement. Also, `{Hours}` is not a legal table name. What is the exact data-type of the `@DateInput` parameter? If we decide your table-design is fundamentally incorrect are you open to redesigning it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to tag Outsystems. Tables are created by the platform. That's the syntax used inside the language, which is based on SQL-Server: {Table}.[Attribute] And @DateInput is a Date type, it will receive the day selected on the calendar.
Hours is a static table that has a list ranging from 0 to 23
Schedule has two foreign keys from Hours as StartHour and EndHour and another linking it to Room as RoomId.

Comment: Please don't verbally describe your tables: just give us the actual `CREATE TABLE` statements for the `Hours` and `Schedule` tables. You can get them from SSMS.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that since the DB is stored on Outsystems Cloud I cannot access it with SSMS. So far I didn't found a way to display the whole DDL.

Comment: @GabrielFreitas Can you run your own arbitrary SQL? If so, as an alternative you could also run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME IN ( 'Hours', 'Schedule' ) ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME, c.ORDINAL_POSITION`.

Comment: Yes I can run arbitrary SQL but the platform has some peculiarities, if I try to EXEC SP_HELP (or SP_COLUMNS) Table it will return an undefined error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the curly bracket notation like `{Hours}`, but I will assume that is an outsystems thing and run with it.

Instead of selecting hours between two values, I believe you need to structure your query to select hours which are not a part of any existing schedule entry. This can be done with a NOT EXISTS() condition. Something like:

```
SELECT H.*
FROM {Hours} H
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {Schedule} S
    WHERE S.RoomId = @RoomInput
    AND (S.StartDate < @DateInput
         OR (S.StartDate = @DateInput AND S.StartHour <= H.Id))
    AND (S.EndDate > @DateInput
         OR (S.EndDate = @DateInput AND S.EndHour >= H.Id))
)
```

Comparisons such as this are usually easier to write if dates and times are combined.

```
    WHERE S.RoomId = @RoomInput
    AND DATEADD(hour, H.Id, @DateInput)
        BETWEEN DATEADD(hour, S.StartHour, S.StartDate)
            AND DATEADD(hour, S.EndHour, S.EndDate)
```

You may need to tweak the end comparison depending on whether EndDate is inclusive or exclusive. (Does a schedule entry with EndHour = 10 end at 10:00 or 11:00?)

For working demos, see

- [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7bb4987e7b15e84bc357ad977c73830c) using inclusive dates.
- [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ca9309e0441023f0b75f1e09c3085d7) using exclusive end dates (where a 1 hour meeting starting at 9am has EndHour = 10).
- [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84989554e37fff6ad81c991162ee1c6a) using combined date/times and exclusive end date/time.

Comment: `BETWEEN DATEADD(hour, S.StartHour, S.StartDate)` <-- This won't be SARGable, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dai Ideally the OP should change the table schema to use combined date/times. Even with the first WHERE clause version, the OR conditions will interfere with optimization beyond the RoomId condition. Best option for current schema may be to index on RoomId with covering references to Start/End Dates & Hours At least then the entire condition could be evaluated with an index range scan.. (Please pardon my imprecise terminology.)

Comment: Added db<> fiddle above.

Comment: This works like a charm. The EndHour is exclusive, just tweaked it. But this somehow didn't worked very well if the StartHour = 0. I made different schedules for the same day and the same room, the one starting from 0 to 8 hours doesn't compute.

Comment: @GabrielFreitas The change for exclusive end date is to just change `>=` to `>` in `S.EndHour > H.Id`. The `S.StartHour <= H.Id` remains unchanged, since that is still inclusive. I added more db<> fiddle variants above. If you are still having issues, please edit the test data in the second (exclusive) fiddle above, capture the updated fiddle URL and paste it in another commend and I'll take a look.